# Is it possible to change the direction of vertex normals in 3.4?

Tags: normals

Is it possible to change the direction of vertex normals like in Mayas normals editor? I just want to point my vertex normals straight up.

The normal modifier is only getting about half of the vertex normals to  point up.

[image]

And I cant get the data transfer to work at all.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean, normal edit modifier doesn't work on vertex normals?  That's exactly what it works on.  Alternative method would be data transfer modifer to get normals (for constant, straight-up normals, target a plane.)

Comment: Ill have to try the data transfer, the normal edit works but only forces about half of the vertex normals towards the target.

Comment: pls provide blend file so we now what you have done and can check it out. thx.

Comment: Hello, @Nathan .. I have to say, I don't understand this behaviour, either. If I set 'Directional' and 'Parallel', Face-Corner Normals all point the right way. So far, so good. But the face-interpolated Vertex-Normals behave inconsistently.. those with no component in the direction of the target don't move at all. Those with a  negative <1 component flip, the ones with a positive <1 component don't move. Personally, I can't reverse-engineer an explanation of this which makes sense. Can you? https://imgur.com/a/DGeQa5K

Comment: @RobinBetts The modifier has a built-in face flip as part of it; face orientation is independent of custom normals. As the custom normal reaches 90 degrees off base, the face flips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a normal edit modifier or a data transfer modifier to set custom normals.  You've indicated you want your normals pointing straight up, so that's what I'll show.

If you use a normal edit modifier, create a target directly above the object origin, and set the modifier to directional and parallel normals:

[image]

With those settings, the vector from the object origin to the target object are adopted as custom normals for all vertices.

If you use a data transfer modifier, create a plane (anywhere) and target it with data transfer face-corner data, enabling custom normals; a variety of interpolation methods will work for this, but nearest face interpolated is a typical, safe method for other uses of this modifier.

[image]

Either of these modifiers can be applied if desired, after which it's safe to delete the target objects (but then, the normals will rotate with the object).